# Nuget - Projects unable to find references after migration to Package Reference from packages.config

Tags: c#, nuget, devexpress, nuget-package

I have a .Net 4.6.2 Winforms application

I have recently migrated all my projects to package reference from packages.config using the [VS Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference),

After the migration certain projects are complaining that they are unable to find the references on build, when first starting VS or when a nuget restore command is ran.

The package i am trying to reference is **Devexpress.Win**
This has transient packages

- Devexpress.Utils
- Devexpress.Data

Example Problem:

- **Project A** - Contains package reference **Devexpress.Win** - Builds fine
- **Project B** - Contains package reference **Devexpress.Win** - Build Fails due to missing reference -

**Error**

> error BC30652: Reference required to assembly 'DevExpress.Utils.v18.1, Version=18.1.6.0, Culture=neutral

**Investigation:**
On further investigation it appears like the "projects.assets.json" file is deleted from the projects obj folder when the project builds. it then has to restored by restarting VS or executing nuget restore, but is then deleted again on build.

Has anyone had this problem? im getting ready to reverse the migration on the projects but was looking for a solution first

Answer (score 1):

Okay so found the issue,

Someone seemed to have added a pre-build event to the project file which was clearing the bin and obj folders before the project build

**Offending code:**

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Remove obj folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <!-- Remove bin folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseOutputPath)" />
  </Target>
```